# Common Lisp loop-macro also collect rest

Tags: loops, split, common-lisp, sequence

I wanted to split a sequence using `LOOP`.
I thought the easiest way would be a loop collecting all elements, but this seems not to be possible with loop.
It would look this way:

```
(loop for i in '(1 2 3 4 5) with-rest rest
      if (not (= i 3))
      collect i
      else
      return (values i rest))
```

It should return the values `(1 2)` and `(3 4 5)`(or maybe `(4 5)` as second value).
Is there a keyword in loop that can do this (or in the iterate system), or is this only possible by writing new macros (or using tagbody)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOOP` can destructure lists into head and tail. Then one would not use `in`, but `on`. You can also collect into a variable.

```
CL-USER 13 > (loop for (i . rest) on '(1 2 3 4 5)
                   if (not (= i 3))
                   collect i into head
                   else return (values head (cons i rest)))
(1 2)
(3 4 5)
```

or

```
CL-USER 16 > (loop with list = '(1 2 3 4 5)
                   for i in list
                   for rest on (rest list)
                   if (not (= i 3))
                   collect i into head
                   else return (values head (cons i rest)))
(1 2)
(3 4 5)
```

Comment: no, `return` works, it also appears in the loop-table in "Land Of Lisp", but `on` is there described as the same as `in`

Comment: @cl-porky11 right, `RETURN` works for this case. I was thinking of the `FINALLY` form...

Answer (score 2):

One terse option that avoids LOOP, but traverses part of the list twice:

```
(let ((tail (member 3 list)))
  (values (ldiff tail list) tail))
```